# Tutorial question 'Using rosmsg' error

Tags: ros, catkin-make, beginner-tutorials, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been going through the tutorials for the first time, but got stuck on the 'Using rosmsg' section.  The command is :  `rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num`, and the error is

```
Unable to load msg [beginner_tutorials/Num]: Cannot locate message [Num]: unknown package [beginner_tutorials] on search path [ ...
```

I tried re-making the package and carefully reviewed the instructions.  I haven't had any other error until now.  Some further information:

- the command: `rossrv show beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts` gives a similar error.
- I am sightly confused over the code section that says:

  > Also make sure you export the message runtime dependency.

  > ```
  > catkin_package(
  > ```

  ```
    ...
    CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
    ...)
  ```

Am I supposed to just uncomment this line only?  I notice in the `CMakeLists.txt` there are a lot of other 'instructions', I have been ignoring them I assume this is correct?

-I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox, I haven't had any issues with it.

The forum won't let me upload files yet.  Thanks for your help.

Perigalacticon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236129/tutorial-question-%27using-rosmsg%27-error/) by [perigaacticon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27072/perigaacticon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-09**:
Hey, were you able to resolve this? If not, can you please edit your question to add your full CMakeLists.txt?

**Comment by [perigaacticon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27072/perigaacticon/) on 2016-06-21**:
Yes I was, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to resource source devel/setup.bash from the catkin workspace and remake.

---

Originally posted by [perigaacticon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27072/perigaacticon/) with karma: 26 on 2016-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0